# Idiomatic way for unique data constructors naming

Tags: haskell

Can I use the *same* name (`name` here) in *different* data types?

```hs
data Person
   = Person
   {
       name   :: String,
       salary :: Int
   }
   deriving( Show )

data University
   = University
   {
--     nameu    :: String, <--- this works fine
       name     :: String,
       students :: [ Person ]
   }
   deriving( Show )

main = putStrLn $ show $ University {
    name = "TAU",
    students = [
        Person { name = "Oren",  salary = 740 },
        Person { name = "Moish", salary = 920 },
        Person { name = "Axel",  salary = 612 }
    ]
}
```

When I try to do it, I get this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )

Main.hs:13:8: error:
    Multiple declarations of ‘name’
    Declared at: Main.hs:4:8
                 Main.hs:13:8
   |
13 |        name     :: String,
   |        ^^^^
```

Comment: No (in Haskell 2010 at least). There are some language extensions for that [one](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/disambiguate_record_fields.html) [two](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/duplicate_record_fields.html) but be careful with extensions.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. thanks. So I guess the common thing to do is `name` and `name_` (?)

Comment: Either that, or move them to separate modules.

Comment: Separating to distinct modules sounds perfect - but I still get the same error (separated to `Person` and `University` and imported both modules to Main)

Comment: You need to import at least one of them qualified, and use University.name and/or Person.name.

Comment: Ohhhh I see ... thanks it works ! to make this thread complete I thought I'd post this as an answer (unless you want to do it yourself?)

Comment: Sure, don't hesitate to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Here is a complete solution from the comments of [n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m)
- I used non qualified imports

```hs
module Person (Person(..)) where
data Person
   = Person
   {
       name   :: String,
       salary :: Int
   }
   deriving( Show )
```

And University module is similar:

```hs
module University (University(..)) where
import Person
data University
   = University
   {
       name     :: String,
       students :: [ Person ]
   }
   deriving( Show )
```

Now Main simply imports both modules

```
import Person
import University

main = putStrLn $ show $ University {
    University.name = "TAU",
    students = [
        Person { Person.name = "Oren",  salary = 740 },
        Person { Person.name = "Moish", salary = 920 },
        Person { Person.name = "Axel",  salary = 612 }
    ]
}
```

Everything compiles fine:

```
$ ghc Main.hs
[1 of 3] Compiling Person           ( Person.hs, Person.o )
[2 of 3] Compiling University       ( University.hs, University.o )
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...
```

and runs:

```
$ ./Main | sed "s/Person/\nPerson/g"
University {name = "TAU", students = [
Person {name = "Oren", salary = 740},
Person {name = "Moish", salary = 920},
Person {name = "Axel", salary = 612}]}
```